BIM360 User Addition using the Autodesk Platform Services (Forge) BIM360 API
My custom integration adds multiple users to a specific BIM project. The problem I am facing is that it will only add account admins and not anyone else. Every time I try to add a non account admin, the code spits out an error that says:

"user must be account admin and project member".

This makes no sense to me as isn't every user in BIM a project member. The documentation on forge for posting users does say that the users only need to be project admins and project users and that's exactly what they are. I attached a link to the documentation below.
Documentation:  https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST/
TLDR - My code works for adding all account admins to any single specific project. It just won't add non account admins.
My code:
// Author: Saheer Multani

const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const ForgeSDK = require('forge-apis');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const CLIENT_ID = '';
const CLIENT_SECRET = '';
const SCOPES = ['data:read', 'data:write', 'account:read', 'account:write'];
const ACCOUNT_ID = '';
const PROJECT_ID = '';

let accessToken = '';

const oAuth2TwoLegged = new ForgeSDK.AuthClientTwoLegged(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, SCOPES, true);

const getAccessToken = async () => {
    try {
        const credentials = await oAuth2TwoLegged.authenticate();
        accessToken = credentials.access_token;
        console.log('Access token:', accessToken);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error getting access token:', error);
    }
};

const addUserToProject = async (userId, email, companyId, roleId, isAdmin) => {
    try {
        const url = `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v2/accounts/${ACCOUNT_ID}/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/users/import`;

        const headers = {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'x-user-id': userId,
            Region: 'US' // Adjust the region based on your deployment
        };

        const userData = {
            email,
            company_id: companyId,
            industry_roles: [roleId],
            services: {
                document_management: {
                    access_level: isAdmin ? 'admin' : 'user'
                }
            }
        };

        if (isAdmin) {
            userData.services.project_administration = {
                access_level: 'admin'
            };
        }

        const data = [userData];

        const response = await axios.post(url, data, { headers });

        if (response.data.failure > 0) {
            console.error('Failed to add user:', response.data.failure_items);
            response.data.failure_items.forEach(item => {
                console.error(`Failed to add user with email: ${item.email}`);
                item.errors.forEach(error => {
                    console.error(`Error code: ${error.code}, message: ${error.message}`);
                });
            });
        } else {
            console.log('User added successfully:', response.data);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            console.error('Error adding user:', error.response.data);
        } else {
            console.error('Error adding user:', error.message);
        }
    }
};

const parseUserList = async (filePath) => {
    try {
        const data = await fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8');
        const lines = data.split('\n').filter(line => line.trim());
        const users = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i += 4) {
            const userId = lines[i].split(':')[1].trim().replace(/'/g, '');
            const email = lines[i + 1].split(':')[1].trim().replace(/'/g, '');
            const companyId = lines[i + 2].split(':')[1].trim().replace(/'/g, '');
            const roleId = lines[i + 3].split(':')[1].trim().replace(/'/g, '');

            users.push({ userId, email, companyId, roleId });
        }

        return users;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error reading user list file:', error);
        return [];
    }
};

const main = async () => {
    await getAccessToken();
    const adminUsers = await parseUserList('admin_user_list.txt');
    const nonAdminUsers = await parseUserList('non_admin_user_list.txt');

    for (const user of adminUsers) {
        await addUserToProject(user.userId, user.email, user.companyId, user.roleId, true);
    }

    for (const user of nonAdminUsers) {
        await addUserToProject(user.userId, user.email, user.companyId, user.roleId, false);
    }
};

main();

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});


